# Flexslider 2 plugin isn't work without connection to internet

Tags: jquery, html, flexslider

I'm new in js ,I added the flexslider 2 plugin, but when my PC is not connected to internet the plugin doesn't work; it's just showing a flexslider class without image.

How to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Presumably, the image is not hosted on your PC (or the image location is specified on an external URI)?

Comment: or may be the flexslider js is a external url

Comment: i put the  image in the same folder

Comment: Have you made sure that you have Jquery available locally? If it's included as an http request then flexslider will fail because jquery can't be loaded and it's a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import all the related images to your pc and change the source path of those images if you plan to try it offline

Generally those images are fetched from a URI and they wont be available when you are offline

Example :

The same happens with jQuery Datepicker if you dont include the UI icons etc..

Comment: i have added it to the same folder ,all image that i need

Comment: have you changed the source path for the image ? @user2924643